# Access package level variables in stored functions written in EnterpriseDB PPAS 9.2

Tags: enterprisedb, postgres-plus

In Oracle we have packages, which we can also use to keep the constant values in one single place.

I want to do the same in postgres 9.2. I don't want to hard code the values at every functions I write.

I know EnterpriseDB Postgres Plus Advanced Server 9.2 version supports packages.

I just created a package as shown below

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE sample.reference_constant
 IS
 v_sample_1 CONSTANT VARCHAR := 'SAMPLE ONE';
 END;
```

When I tried to access the variable like `pkg_name.variable_name` in the function body, I'm just getting an invalid SELECT operation error.

Can anybody tell me **how to access the package level variable in EDB PPAS?

Cheers,
-AP

Comment: That's not PostgreSQL. Are you sure you're really using PostgreSQL, not, say, EnterpriseDB Postgres Plus?

Comment: Postgres plus advanced server 9.3 in Postgres Enterprise Manager V 4.0.0

Comment: Very few people from EDB hang out here. Try their forums.

Comment: Thank you for the edit and for showing the right direction.

Comment: If you get an answer there, please post a self-answer linking back to it here.

Comment: Sure thats why I didn't close this question yet... Will post back once I got it.